# Exporting R to vector-based designed charts

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm looking for ways to visualize data in vector-based images through R. Here are links to some examples of something I'm having designed:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2195053-The-Truth-About-B-zier-Graphs/attachments/405731

https://dribbble.com/shots/1728095-Line-Chart/attachments/278191

I understand there are some R libraries for SVG and other file types that permit export to higher quality designs, but haven't seen any tutorials or tools. Any direction is appreciated. I'm not even sure what steps would be necessary to dynamically generate charts like that through R.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your question about generating vector versions of R plots, or having the extraneous ("high quality") embellishments directly within R? You can export PDF of charts in R and use that as the basis of your fancy version. I don't think you'll find easy ways to do drop shadows highlights, but the "Truth about Bezier Graphs" could likely be emulated as a ggplot style.

Comment: I don't want to try to copy it in R. R isn't equipped for that kind of design. I want R to generate the data and have that be exported to some program that can render the graph.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you are looking for the `pdf(file="myplot.pdf")` command? This opens a graphics device to save whatever plots or graphs you generate up until you use `dev.off()` Don't quote me on this since from memory but that should get you a graphics object you can import...

Comment: Have a look at `RSvgDevice` https://github.com/mdecorde/RSvgDevice especially the expected-to-be-pulled `editSVG` https://github.com/mdecorde/RSvgDevice/pull/30 function which I think might be just what you are looking for as a starting point.  I am highly interested in your workflow and would like to be able to incorporate it into this new package. Please let me know your thoughts.